# NSTextField not visible

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I recently started coding Swift. So I am working on a macOS app to get more used to Swift.

I want that an NSTextField is created when the user presses a button. I got the code below but the NSTextField doesn't display. While research I found that it somehow must be added to view but not how this is done.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let label = NSTextField()
    label.stringValue = ("Hello World")   
}
```

How do I make the NSTextField display? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You create the text field but you do not add it to any parent view or set its frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let rect = NSMakeRect(20, 20, 80, 44)
let label = NSTextField(frame: rect)
view.addSubview(label)
```

Worked for me. In Xcode 10 with swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the label into a layer-backed view. Then add it into a visible view:

```
let rect = NSMakeRect(20, 20, 80, 44)
let label = NSTextField(frame: rect)
label.wantsLayer = true
label.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.greenColor().CGColor
window?.contentView?.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Why not make the text field a subview of the view controller's view?

Comment: The code doesn't work, Xcode returns "Use of unresolved identifier 'window'"

Comment: @TobiasWilfert Change `window?.contentView?` to `view`.

Comment: Why "turn the label into a layer-backed view"?